# Laravel Date Grouping using Eloquent Query

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, eloquent

I have dates july 1, july 2, aug 1, sep 1, nov 1, aug 2 in my database. I loop through the dates so the outcome  is this.

[image]

How can I get 1 July month even though it has the same month using eloquent so that the outcome will be like this?
[image]

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Test Type</th>
                <?php
                    $types = Tblreporttype::all();
                ?>
                @foreach($types as $type)
                    <?php  
                        $dates = Tblreportdate::with('tblreporttype')
                            ->groupBy('fDate')
                            ->where('tblreporttype_id', '=', $type->id)
                            ->get();
                    ?>
                    @foreach($dates as $date)
                    <?php
                        $convert = $date->fDate;
                        $my_date = date('M/y', strtotime($convert));
                    ?>
                        <th width="100">
                            <?php
                                if($my_date == $my_date) {
                                    echo $my_date;
                                }
                            ?>
                        </th>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <?php  
                    $dates = Tblreportdate::with('tblreporttype')
                    ->groupBy('fDate')
                    ->get();
                ?>
                <?php
                    $types = Tblreporttype::all();
                ?>
                        @foreach($types as $type)
            <tr>
                            <td width="200">{{ $type->fType }}</td>
                        @foreach($dates as $date)
                        <?php
                            $convert = $date->fDate;
                            $my_date = date('d', strtotime($convert));
                        ?>
                        <td width="100">
                            <?php
                                if($date->tblreporttype->id == $type->id) {
                                    echo $my_date; 
                                } else {
                                echo " ";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    @endforeach
            </tr>
                @endforeach
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: Can you at least post your current code?

Comment: The output is different but the idea still the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using Eloquent.

But you can try a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($dates as $date)
{
    $convert = $date->fDate;
    $month = date('M', strtotime($convert));
    $day = date('d', strtotime($convert));
    $date_array[$month][] = $day;
}
```

In your case that should give you an array like this one:

```
array (size=4)
  'Jul' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '01' (length=2)
      1 => string '02' (length=2)
  'Aug' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '01' (length=2)
      1 => string '02' (length=2)
  'Sep' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '01' (length=2)
  'Nov' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '01' (length=2)
```

And you can use a foreach to display it the way you want, something like this:

```
@foreach ($date_array as $month => $days)
    echo $month;
    @foreach ($days as $day)
        echo $day;
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Edit:

I find this Eloquent/Fluent query that should do the job :

```
$dates = DB::table('your_table')
->select(DB::raw('MONTH(date) as month'),DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(date)) as days'))
->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(date)'))->get();
```

Which return a object like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'month' => int 1
      public 'days' => string '1,2' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'month' => int 2
      public 'days' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: how can i add spaces so that it is aligned with the month?